# Windows Update Group Policy removed but still can't run updates

Tags: group-policy, wsus

I've had the Group Policy removed from my account, and from my local machine so that I can run Windows Updates on my computer rather than waiting for them from the Administrators.

But even with all this removed it still blocks the updates and says they are managed by the Administrator.

The Ops aren't sure why it's not working.

How can I figure out what's wrong?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the following reg keys:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer -> NoWindowsUpdate

This should remove all restrictions.
Make sure that GPO really does not apply to you anymore.

Comment: Yeah those are all gone, well they are turned off. WSUS is set to blank, and updates are all on 0 not 1.

Comment: OH, I just found `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/Explorer` which has `NoWindowsUpdate` in it, removed that. Logged off and back on. Windows Updates Available!!!!

Comment: @Phill, why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs wont let me yet. Have to wait until tomorrow. :(

Comment: I edited my answer to include your key as well.

Answer (score 1):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
"DisableWindowsUpdateAccess"=dword:00000000

Set to zero